# Merging data frames with dataframe source as column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, unique

I have two data frames

df1

```
##   day time  temp activ
## 1 346  840 36.33     0
## 2 346  850 36.34     0
## 3 346  900 36.35     0
## 4 346  910 36.42     0
## 5 346  920 36.55     0
## 6 346  930 36.69     0
```

And df2

```
  day time  temp activ
   1 307  930 36.58     0
## 2 307  940 36.73     0
## 3 307  950 36.93     0
## 4 307 1000 37.15     0
## 5 307 1010 37.23     0
## 6 307 1020 37.24     0
```

I'm having trouble creating another column that lists which dataframe the row came from (df1 or df2) such that the merged df looks like such, for df1/df2 data respectively.

```
    day time  temp activ df_origin
1   307  930 36.58     0 df1
2   307  940 36.73     0 df1
3   307  950 36.93     0 df1
4   307 1000 37.15     0 df1
```

Comment: `307  930 36.58     0` this comes from `df2` but you say `df1` in your deisred output? how so?

Comment: But doesn't "merge" imply the values in each row come from both data frames?  Do you mean `rbind` instead of `merge`?

Comment: the merged df (df3) includes the values of df1 but in this example I only printed the first 5 lines.. 

My merge function I used was merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)

Answer (score 2):

Just add a column to each one, before you merge:

```
df1$df_origin <- 'df1'
df2$df_origin <- 'df2'
```

Comment: thank you!  I was trying to mess with the merge() function in order to input this but this is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

We can place the datasets in a `list` and use `Map` to create the column at once

```
lst <- mget(paste0("df", 1:2))
lst <- Map(cbind, lst, df_origin = names(lst))
```